# Efficient code to do a countif, ranking on huge csv file

Tags: csv, perl

need help to accelerate the run of below perl code.  4 to 6hours should be fine.  faster is better :)
csv file is about 14m to 14.5m rows, and aorund 1100 to 1500columns; 62gig
what it does:

- do a count (like a countif in excel)
- get the percent (based on 14m rows)
- get the rank based on count

### My current code:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
$x="Room_reserve";
$in = "D:\\package properties\\${x}.csv";
$out = "D:\\package properties\\output\\${x}_output.csv";

open($fh, '<', $in) or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";
@data = <$fh>;
close($fh);

%counts;
@columns;
$first = 1;

#counter
foreach $dat (@data) {
    chomp($dat);
    @rows = split(',',$dat);
    if ($first == 1) {
        $first = 0;
        next;
    }
    else {
        $count = 1;
        foreach $i (0..$#rows) {
            if ( exists($columns[$i]{$rows[$i]}) ) {
                $columns[$i]{$rows[$i]}++;
            }
            else {
                $columns[$i]{$rows[$i]} = int($count);
            }
        }
    }
}

#output
$first = 1;
open($fh, '>', $out) or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";
foreach $dat (@data) {
    chomp($dat);
    @rows = split(',',$dat);
    foreach $i (0..$#rows) {
        if ($i > 6) {
            #for modifying name
            if ( $first == 1 ) {
                $line = join( ",", "Rank_$rows[$i]", "Percent_$rows[$i]",
                              "Count_$rows[$i]", $rows[$i]);
                print $fh "$line,";
                if ( $i == $#rows ) {
                    $first = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                @dat_val = reverse sort { $a <=> $b } values %{$columns[$i]};
                %ranks = {};
                $rank_cnt = 0;
                foreach $val (@dat_val) {
                    if ( ! exists($ranks{$val}) ) {
                        $rank_cnt++;
                    }
                    $ranks{$val} = $rank_cnt;
                }
                $rank = $ranks{$columns[$i]{$rows[$i]}};
                $cnt = $columns[$i]{$rows[$i]};
                $ave = ($cnt / 14000000) * 100;
                $line = join( ",", $rank, $ave, $cnt, $rows[$i]);
                print $fh "$line,";
            }
        }
        else {
            print $fh "$rows[$i],";
        }
    }
    print $fh "\n";
}
close($fh);
```

thanks in advance.

### my table

| Col | _1 | _2 | _3 | _4 | _5 | _6 | Col2 | Col3 | Col | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 4 |
| FALSE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 4 |
| FALSE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 3 |

edited to show sample table and correct $x

##Sample output

| Col | _1 | _2 | _3 | _4 | _5 | _6 | Col2 | rank_Col2 | percent_rank_Col2 | count_Col2 | Col3 | rank_Col3 | percent_rank_Col3 | count_Col3 | Col | rank_Col | percent_rank_Col | count_Col | Col5 | rank_Col5 | percent_rank_Col5 | count_Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 2 | 0.33 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 0.67 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0.67 | 2 | 11 | 1 | 0.33 | 1 |
| FALSE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 0.67 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 0.67 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0.33 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 0.33 | 1 |
| FALSE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 0.67 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 0.33 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.67 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0.33 | 1 |

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings` and fix the errors and warnings that appear. Never write Perl code without using these two pragmas. Then look into `Text::CSV_XS`, which I hear is very fast.

Comment: Also, slurping the file into an array is bound to slow you down if the file is 62Gb. That will eat all your memory.

Comment: Nice that you posted your code, but we'd need to see a sample from that data file and an explanation of what you need done with that data.  I can't do anything about this if I don't know what your data looks like and what you need to do with it. (Can't study all this code to figure out what it does, and I have no clue what "count," "percent," or "rank" you need -- or what "countif" is.)

Comment: Sorry, I can't add in properly as a table and also cannot add an image

Comment: @theo Use the edit button and add it to your question. Don't add it in comments. And don't show data or code in images, use copy paste

Comment: @theo Your $x variable contains the file extension so when you insert it into $in you will end up with the file extension twice. Is this the actual code you are using? You might consider using a small, toy version of your data to post here for help and show the actual code you are running.

Comment: @theo Can you also include a small sample of the CSV input file as **text** (so that we can copy and paste) ?

Comment: @theo Also give an example of how the expected output file should look like.

Comment: @theo It seems like the first 7 columns in `@columns` are not used for anything? Maybe you could speed it up by not saving those columns?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following script? It precomputes the ranks instead of recalculating them for each row. It also avoids saving the first 7 columns in `@columns` since they appear not to be used for anything.

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my $x="Room_reserve";
    my $in = "D:\\package properties\\${x}.csv";
    my $out = "D:\\package properties\\output\\${x}_output.csv";
    my $min_col = 7;
    my ($data1, $data2) = read_input_file($in, $min_col);
    my $columns = create_counter($data2);
    my $ranks = create_ranks( $columns);
    write_output($data1, $data2, $columns, $ranks, $min_col, $out);
}

sub create_counter {
    my ($data) = @_;

    print "Creating counter..";
    my @columns;
    my $first = 1;
    for my $row (@$data) {
        if ( $first ) {
            $first = 0; next;  # skip header
        }
        for my $i (0..$#$row) {
            $columns[$i]{$row->[$i]}++;
        }
    }
    say "done.";
    return \@columns;
}

sub create_ranks {
    my ( $columns ) = @_;

    print "Creating ranks..";
    my @ranks;
    for my $col (@$columns) {
        # sort the column values according to highest frequency.
        my @freqs = sort { $b <=> $a } values %$col;
        my $idx = 1;
        my %ranks = map {$_ => $idx++} @freqs;
        push @ranks, \%ranks;
    }
    say "done.";
    return \@ranks;
}

sub read_input_file {
    my ($in, $min_col) = @_;

    print "Reading input file $in ..";
    open(my $fh, '<', $in) or die "Could not open file '$in' $!";
    my @data1;
    my @data2;
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my @fields = split(',', $line);
        next if @fields == 0;
        die "Unexpected column count at line $.\n" if @fields < $min_col;
        push @data1, [@fields[0..($min_col-1)]];
        push @data2, [@fields[$min_col..$#fields]];
    }
    say " $. lines.";
    close($fh);
    return \@data1, \@data2;
}

sub write_output {
    my ($data1, $data2, $columns, $ranks, $min_col, $out) = @_;

    say "Saving output file $out..";
    open(my $fh, '>', $out) or die "Could not open file '$out': $!";
    for my $i (0..$#$data1) {
        my $row1 = $data1->[$i];
        my $row2 = $data2->[$i];
        if ($i == 0) {
            print $fh join ",", @$row1;
            print $fh ",";
            for my $j (0..$#$row2) {
                print $fh join ",", $row2->[$j],
                  "Rank_" . $row2->[$j],
                  "Percent_". $row2->[$j],
                  "Count_" . $row2->[$j];
                print $fh "," if $j < $#$row2;
            }
            print $fh "\n";
            next;
        }
        print $fh join ",", @$row1;
        print $fh ",";
        for my $j (0..$#$row2) {
            my $cnt = $columns->[$j]{$row2->[$j]};
            my $rank = $ranks->[$j]{$cnt};
            my $ave = ($cnt / 14000000) * 100;
            print $fh join ",", $row2->[$j], $rank, $ave, $cnt;
            print $fh "," if $j < $#$row2;
        }
        print $fh "\n";
    }
    close $fh;
    say "Done.";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hakon, thank you for provided your code.  I was able to try it just now for small files first.  The output have some issues though result is correct.  The issue is that the count column merged with the next original column, example: **count_col2Col3**, **count_col3col4**.  I cannot decipher which one needs to be modified

Comment: @theo Yes, I can see I forgot to add a comma separator when printing the header.. Can you try my updated code?

Comment: Hi @Hakon, the data are also impacted by the way.  The new code addressed the header but need to separate the entries as well.  Thanks for looking into this

Comment: @theo See updated answer. Does it work ok now?

Comment: yes.  Thank you. will run the big file and let you know if it runs faster.

Comment: Hi @Hakno, your code is still runningfor about 3 hours now.  
A few comments:
- there seems to be an issue with ranking, some columns jump a rank (this is on the 100000 sample); eg on col3, the ranks are 1-25, jump to 25, next is 27.
- the good thing is it's using less memory than my code
-however, another issue is that the perl or cmd is not accessible during running.  Hopefully, will not have impact on the result.

Comment: Ok, how long time did your original code use? How much RAM memory do you have on your machine?

Comment: 8+ hours is required in my original code.  and I have 16gig of RAM.  
your code will use max of 4 gig so far, my original code would use almost 11gig

Answer (score 1):

Presume you have this file:

```
% ls -lh file
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel  57G Jul 24 13:15 file
% time wc -l file
 14000000 file
wc -l file  29.24s user 7.27s system 99% cpu 36.508 total
% awk -F, 'FNR==1{print $NF; exit}' file
1099
```

So we have a 57GB file with 14,000,000 line by 1099 col csv with random numbers.

It only takes 20 to 30 SECONDS to read the entire file in a line-by-line fashion.

How long in Perl?

```
% time perl  -lnE '' file
perl -lnE '' file  5.70s user 9.67s system 99% cpu 15.381 total
```

So only 15 seconds in Perl line by line. How long to 'gulp' it?

```
% time perl  -0777 -lnE '' file
perl -0777 -lnE '' file  12.13s user 23.86s system 98% cpu 36.688 total
```

But that is on *THIS* computer which has 255GB of RAM...

It took this Python script approximately 23 minutes to write that file:

```
total=0
cols=1100
with open('/tmp/file', 'w') as f_out:
    for cnt in range(14_000_000):
        line=','.join(f'{x}' for x in range(cols))
        total+=cols
        f_out.write(f'{cnt},{total},{line}\n')
```

The issue with your Perl script is you are gulping the whole file (with `@data = <$fh>;`) and the OS maybe is running out of RAM. It is likely swapping and this is very slow. (How much RAM do you have?)

Rewrite the script to do it line by line. You should be able to do your entire analysis in less than 1 hour.